# Vertica C.E. cluster node number?

Tags: database, vertica

How many nodes can be created in Vertica C.E. Database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say 3, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: -that is true ,i have installed 3 nodes at start installation and tried to remove a node or add a new node , with no succes !!<br/>and the error msg are not that intuitive !! also !! thx !!

Answer (score 1):

Limitations of vertica community edition:

1. 3 nodes can be created
2. 1 TB of data you can load or maintain
3. Driver support only for Linux and Windows

Answer (score 0):

The CE is limited to 3 nodes and 1 TB of data.